# Get data from cell As items for dropdown's item in app designer in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, matlab-app-designer

I have a cell like this (in matlab) :

```
students = cell (3,3)

students ---->   {1}  {'frank'}   {[10,17,19]}
                 {2}  {'yasin'}   {[19,18,17]}
                 {3}  {'karim'}   {[12,18,15]}
```

And i have a dropdown (for example: dropdown1)  (in app designer in matlab) . i want to show all student names in dropdown .

If i have this cell:  `testItems = {'aa' , 'bb' ,'ccc'}` , so i should use : `dropdown1.Items = testItems`

But now , how i can use all student names as items for dropdown ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need to extract the name column?

```
dropdown1.Items = students(:, 2);
```